# Async Await Return Task Null .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, async-await

I've a method like this:

```cs
public async Task<Response> HandleRequest(string connectionId, Request request)
{
  if (request is AuthorizeRequest)
  {
    return await _handler.HandleRequest(connectionId, request as AuthorizeRequest);
  }

  if (request is ChangeConfigurationRequest)
  {
    return await _handler.HandleRequest(connectionId, request as ChangeConfigurationRequest);
  }

  return await Task.FromResult<Response>(null);  //My question is here
}
```

My question is: Should I return return await Task.FromResult(null); or retun null;
Because if request is not 'AuthorizeRequest' and 'ChangeConfigurationRequest'

Tks all for helps

Answer (score 2):

Since your method is marked as `async`, you should return `null`.

Comment: Tks Peres, I search from many resources and it said that we should not return null in Task. Is it right?

Comment: And how about my method like this: ``` public Task<Response> HandleRequest(string connectionId, Request request)
        {
            return Task.FromResult<Response>(null);
        }```

Comment: Yes, that would be correct, IMO, without the async modifier.

Answer (score 2):

> I search from many resources and it said that we should not return null in Task. Is it right?

Methods that return a task should never return a `null` task. However, what you want to do is return a (non-`null`) task that contains a result value of `null`. That's fine; it's completely different than returning a `null` task.

For your original code, use `return null;`. Do not ever use `await Task.FromResult(...)`.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but when would one ever need to use Task.FromResult()? Is it only when we are dealing with a method that is not async returns a Task? Is there ever a reason in modern C# to have a method that returns a Task without also being async anyway?

Comment: It's rare. Most of my use cases are test stubs implementing async interfaces.